# How to append and prepend HTML substrings into a matched string using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to search through a string of text for words that start with '#' (hashtags) and append/prepend HTML `<a>#link</a>` link tags to the word. I have come up with the regexp below:

```
string = '#hello here are some #text'
return re.sub('^#\w*|(?<=\s)#\w*', '<a href="{{url_for("main.tag")}}">#\1</a>', string)
```

It returns:

```
<a href="{{url_for("main.tag")}}">#\x01</a> here is some <a href="{{url_for("main.tag")}}">#\x01</a>
```

There's just one small issue: **it doesn't include the matched word**. What needs to be done to the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
re.sub('(^#\w*|(?<=\s)#\w*)', r'<a href="{{url_for("main.tag")}}">\1</a>', string)
```

*Reason*

i) There were no capturing groups. Included one

ii) You can use raw string `r` literal as you are substituting for 
capturing group (or `\\1` if you are not using `r`)

iii) No need of including `#` as it is already captured

Comment: Thanks! I had originally surrounded the regex in parenthesis but it didn't work so I am guessing it has to do with 'r'? Byte string right?

Comment: @user5796559 as mentioned, you can use(`\\1` instead of `\1`) `re.sub('(^#\w*|(?<=\s)#\w*)', '<a href="{{url_for("main.tag")}}">\\1</a>', string)`